# Send data to multiple Azure Log Analytics From ADF

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-appservice

We have data in parquet/json in the storage account and we need to send it to multiple log analytics(LA) destination, depending on the configuration

today, we have a app service in azure which reads the data row by row, for each row it calls  external API to get destination log analytics configuration and sends the data there. This solution is very inefficient.

We can call the external API upfront and partition the data so that one partition data will will have only one single LA destination. But after that what is the best way to send this data to LA?

ADF does not support LA as a destination.
We cannot have spark processor as well that we can call in ADF, as spark does not have good support for LA

One option is to call Azure Function App from ADF, and send data to LA, but I don't know how efficient it would be for large amount of data/files

What could possibly be the other better options here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the logs already partitioned per log analytics workspace destination, you can use the API with up to 30MB per post request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/create-request

This is still in preview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api